# Drawing a Mcculloch-Pitts-Neuron that expresses (x1andx2)orx3

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, computer-science

I understand the the neuron of the logical and operator looks like this.
[image: logical and]

the logical OR of the McCulloch Neuron looks like this.
[image: ligical or]

My question is how can I combine both of these logical operators if I should draw a neuron architecture that expresses (x1andx2)or x3?

This is my approach but I am not sure if it is correct

Could anyone confirm it's correct or if it's wrong tell me what I should change?

Thank you in advance

[image: logical and , and logical or]

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this

- Make use of two separate models, in your case `boolen AND` followed by `boolean OR`. `X1 and X2` are inputs to the `AND` model and the output `x1 AND x2` is one of the inputs along with `X3` to the `OR` model.
- A better method is to create a new model with different weights. You can do this by creating a truth table for the expressions, find out if the expression is linearly separable and choose the type of model accordingly.

```
Linear separable -> single layer
Linear inseparable -> multi layer (ex. XOR gate)
```